# "proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons" - PHP Error

Tags: php

> proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons

I'm with free hosting at the moment (Hostinger) - Making a personal site for my use only and a few others.

I know I am supposed to remove the `proc_open` from the **php.ini** but I can't access it due to my shared hosting plan.

The code surrounding the `proc_open` in my code is as follows - If you require the full code please let me know. I've tried commenting parts out but it returns errors.

All I want is to remove it and allow for the code to run fine.

```
<?php
// Initializing
if (!isset($ACCOUNTS)) $ACCOUNTS = array();
if (isset($USER) && isset($PASSWORD) && $USER && $PASSWORD) $ACCOUNTS[$USER] = $PASSWORD;
if (!isset($HOME_DIRECTORY)) $HOME_DIRECTORY = '';
$IS_CONFIGURED = count($ACCOUNTS) >= 1 ? true : false;

// Command execution
function execute_command($command) {
    $descriptors = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // STDIN
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // STDOUT
        2 => array('pipe', 'w')  // STDERR
    );

    $process = proc_open($command . ' 2>&1', $descriptors, $pipes);
    if (!is_resource($process)) die("Can't execute command.");

    // Nothing to push to STDIN
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    // All pipes must be closed before "proc_close"
    $code = proc_close($process);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is to remove the whole function `execute_command`. 

On a free a account with Hostinger, you do not have access to run shell commands, and will probably never be allowed to do so

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will be moving to a new hosting once I've finished working on it. So I could remove whole command and it would work yes? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure the script will run, if it needs to run shell scripts...

Comment: Why do you even need to run shell commands on a personal site?

Comment: How did you resolve this issues?

Answer (score 4):

You may try to overwrite default php.ini. In the past, I used to successful with another share host, follow this step

1. You create your own php.ini in your web folder. No need to have all value in php.ini, just something you want to overwrite. For example your php.ini may only have one line like this

   ```
   disable_functions = exec,execl,system,passthru,shell_exec,set_time_limit,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,proc_close,ini_alter,proc_open,dl,popen,show_source,posix_getpwuid,getpwuid,posix_geteuid,posix_getegid,posix_getgrgid,open_basedir,safe_mode_include_dir,pcntl_exec,pcntl_fork,putenv,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_terminate,pclose,virtual,openlog,popen,pclose,virtual,openlog,escapeshellcmd,escapeshellarg,dl,show_source,symlink,eval,mail
   ```

Remember to remove proc_open from disable functions

2. Create .htaccess and add this

   ```
   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
   suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/public_html
   </IfModule>
   ```

Remember to change /home/user/public_html with your path

Comment: I tried same way but issue persists on projects. Is there any other method to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by editing this file 
**vendor->facade->ignition->config->flare.php line 29**

```
'collect_git_information' => true,  <---- Change this value to false
```

Laravel 6

PHP 7.3

Comment: after setting collect_git_information false you can see the actual error, then fix that error and you can again set it to true if you keep laravel core code to original