# Shared Hosting proc_get_status has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to upload my laravel app to Cpanel. I set up everything right. It gives me the following error, though.

Please tell me how I can solve this problem?

> proc_get_status() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33401630/5581565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `proc_get_status` from `php.ini`'s disabled functions in Cpanel

```
disable_functions = exec,execl,system,passthru,shell_exec,set_time_limit,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,proc_close,ini_alter,proc_open,dl,popen,show_source,posix_getpwuid,getpwuid,posix_geteuid,posix_getegid,posix_getgrgid,open_basedir,safe_mode_include_dir,pcntl_exec,pcntl_fork,putenv,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_terminate,pclose,virtual,openlog,popen,pclose,virtual,openlog,escapeshellcmd,escapeshellarg,dl,show_source,symlink,eval,mail
```

Then override the config in Apache web server `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  suPHP_ConfigPath /home/path/to/public_html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I'm uploading other Laravel app, it's just working fine. I can't find the php.ini file in cpanel, either.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the fact that on most shared host, you cannot edit the disable_functions property

Comment: In DirectAdmin go to `Select PHP version` --> `options` and edit the `disabled_functions` input (the third from the top at my webhoster). Remove `proc_get-status` as mentioned above. Overwriting the `.htaccess` file should not be necessary.